# Request failed with status code 404 when passing items to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

First of all, I'm a real beginner to programming and I can't figure out what is wrong with this
it only shows an error of 404 not found

Below is my mongoose schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  order_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },

  total_items: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  total: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  address: {
    type: String,
  },
  postalcode: {
    type: String,
  },
  city: {
    type: String,
  },
  country: {
    type: String,
  },
  phonenumber: {
    type: Number,
  },
  order_item_status: {
    //purchased item delivery status, added by constant at saving from controller nmethod
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  quantity_array: [
    {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  ],

  purchase_array: [
    {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  ],

  item_array: [
    {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = Order = mongoose.model("order", OrderSchema);
```

And Below is the set of data that I'm sending.

```
{"user_id":"5f5058acc90b575a40d9e570",
"name":"Alfonso",
"address":"Victoria",
"postalcode":"11011B",
"city":"Moscow",
"country":"Russia",
"phonenumber":null,
"total_items":2,
"total":15,
"quantity_array":[2,1],
"purchase_array":["pb_single","pb_single"],
"item_array":["5f55e91271b808206c132d7c","5f55e8e171b808206c132d7a"]}
```

and below is the function that I use to send the above Object to the server.

```
let orderComplete = {
      user_id: localStorage.getItem("id"),
      name: this.state.name,
      address: this.state.address,
      postalcode: this.state.postalcode,
      city: this.state.city,
      country: this.state.country,
      phonenumber: this.state.phonenumber,
      total_items: this.state.totalitems,
      total: this.state.amount,
      quantity_array: this.state.quantityArray,
      purchase_array: this.state.purchaseTypeArray,
      item_array: this.state.comicIdArray,
    };
    console.log("checkpoint : orderComplete" + JSON.stringify(orderComplete));
    var jwt_token = localStorage.getItem("currentToken"); //because it is a protected route
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "x-auth-token": jwt_token,
      },
    };
    const body = JSON.stringify(orderComplete);
    const result = await axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/createorder", body, config)
      .then((res2) => {
        console.log(res2);
        toast.success(res2);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        toast.error(error);
        console.log(error);
      });

    if (result == true) {
      this.props.history.push("/products");
      toast.success("Order Success");
    }
  }
```

And when it is caught from the server-side
the function is as below

```
const createOrder = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let user_id = req.body.user_id;
    let purchase_type = req.body.purchase_type;
    let item_array = req.body.item_array;
    let quantity_array = req.body.quantity_array;
    let purchase_array = req.body.purchase_array;
    let total_items = req.body.total_items;
    let total = req.body.total;
    let name = req.body.name;
    let address = req.body.address;
    let postalcode = req.body.postalcode;
    let city = req.body.city;
    let country = req.body.country;
    let phonenumber = req.body.phonenumber;

    let order_item_status = "processing";

    if (
      purchase_type == false ||
      user_id == false ||
      item_array == false ||
      quantity_array == false ||
      purchase_array == false ||
      total_items == false ||
      total == false ||
      name == false ||
      address == false ||
      postalcode == false ||
      city == false ||
      country == false ||
      phonenumber == false
    ) {
      return res.status(400).send("Not all mandatory values have been set!");
    }

    OrderObject = new Order({
      //create  object to set data
      purchase_type,
      user_id,
      item_array,
      quantity_array,
      purchase_array,
      total_items,
      total,
      name,
      address,
      postalcode,
      city,
      country,
      phonenumber,
      order_item_status,
    });

    await OrderObject.save();
    res.status(200).send("Order success");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error caught at ", error);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
};
```

I tried over and over but I can't figure out what is wrong with it, Even the exception handlers don't include much of information.

please I desperately need your help, thank you.

Comment: 404 is a page not found status code issue. Assuming your api is well built, have you checked the endpoint you are trying to hit? try sending this data `http://localhost:5000/createorder`  in postman and actually confirm  in the backend that the endpoint exists

Comment: Have you add any server side routes to process the request?

Comment: @myrdstom you just saved my day, it was that i forgot to mention a server end router to the app.js. Thank you very much guys

Comment: Awesome :) glad you figured it out